# Link is Not Starting at Top of Div

Tags: bootstrap-4

I started working with some bootstrap 4 demo theme.

When I create links to go to parts of the same page - they go a bit too far and I loose the 1st few lines of that div so i have to scroll back a bit to see the start. In this example - it might start around 'content3' or so.

It seems like there is some kind of offset that may be doing this? I wouldn't know where to find it.

Any ideas how to adjust this to not go past the start of the div?

```
<a href="#here1" >MY INFO goooo</a>

<div id="here1" class="container text-center">
content1<br>
content2<br>
content3<br>
content4 etc....<br>
</div>
```

Thanks - Dave

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue, seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your website has a fixed header you may have noticed that anchor tag links don’t work perfectly – when a user uses anchor link the location of the anchor becomes hidden behind the fixed header, hiding the first part of the content.

This method does not involve any JavaScript or require changes to your theme or content.

in your HTML:

```
<a class="anchor" id="top"></a>
```

---

To fix this you can add the following to your CSS style sheet.

Here's one fix I applied:

for your CSS:

```
a.anchor {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -250px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Here's another method:

```
:target:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    height:90px; /* fixed header height*/
    margin:-90px 0 0; /* negative fixed header height */
}
```

**Note**: 90px is the height of the fixed header plus margin and padding. You will need to adjust this to the size of your fixed header.

The **drawbacks** are that it requires browser support for pseudo-elements and it will fail if the target element has a background color, a repeated background image, padding-top, or border-top as part of its rule set.

**Learn more** methods and their pros and cons here: [Jump links and viewport positioning](http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/#method-E)

---

This solution uses JS:

```
var shiftWindow = function() { scrollBy(0, -50) };
if (location.hash) shiftWindow();
window.addEventListener("hashchange", shiftWindow);
```

You can read more about other user solutions [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768).

Comment: Thank you so much sunsetsurf - This is super helpful - many possibilities!

Comment: I found this also from one of your link and it seems to work well

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768

`
    *[id]:before { 
    display: block; 
    content: " "; 
    margin-top: -75px; 
    height: 75px; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    }`

Answer (score 2):

```
function scrollToDiv(divID){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + divID).offset().top - 50
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: So sorry for the very long delay getting back to you. I just learned about voting and comments and want to thank you for your efforts.